# Fat Free Error Trace Not Always Visible

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I have my `DEBUG` set in the F3 hive to `2`.

On some servers/error, the full error message and trace, including files and line numbers is visible. Other times it isn't. What am I missing?

Shouldn't F3 automatically set the PHP `error_reporting()` and related values despite the settings of my server? Why don't I have a consistent result with this setting?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Maybe related to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/f3-framework/QuTeC8-1VsQ). I'd advise you to post details about this on Google Groups or to file an issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment on the following lines during development mode.

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
// Deprecated directives
@ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc',0);
@ini_set('register_globals',0);
// Abort on startup error
// Intercept errors/exceptions; PHP5.3-compatible
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
 $fw=$this;
set_exception_handler(
function($obj) use($fw) {
    $fw->error(500,$obj->getmessage(),$obj->gettrace());
}
);
  set_error_handler(
     function($code,$text) use($fw) {
     if (error_reporting())
    $fw->error(500,$text);
 }
);
```

Remember to uncomment when you deploy the app.
I had that problem too, the php error handler is simpler in finding errors in code